# Why do we have exactly three parameters to describe relationship between current and voltage in linear elements?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor

I was simply pondering over everything I learned about circuits and electricity and there was this one question I couldn't give a simple answer to. Why exactly do we need only these three parameters of capacitance, inductance, and resistance to describe every voltage-current relationship in linear circuits?

One may bring up impedance and say the quantity of impedance unifies these three things and there is only one quantity that controls the relation between voltage and current but even then the question remains, why the impedance is said to be made of these three unique parts.

Thanks!

---

p.s: One may say there are other factors that control the relationship such as the geometry of the object, but that is really captured as a whole in each of these three things already.

[Follow up](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571681/simple-examples-of-second-order-circuits-and-quantities-required-to-describe-the)

Comment: They aren't enough to capture all possible behaviour. If you add voltage sources or equivalently current sources, including dependent sources, you can then describe all possible *linear* behaviour, but nonlinear elements exist and are particularly important.

Comment: Well sure, however, my question isn't about what the basic things we need to span all possible electronics are but the current-voltage relation can be decomposed into relations involving the three mentioned quantities @Hearth

Comment: @Buraian but that's what Hearth is all about: You simply can't. Your assumption that you can is wrong.

Comment: How familiar are you with the Laplace domain? It may make more sense to think of resistors, inductors, and capacitors respectively as as resistance, reactance with a positive frequency dependence, and reactance with a negative frequency dependence.

Comment: I've heard of the Laplace transform and seen some videos of how the integration extracts out all the frequencies corresponding to a function but I am not too familiar with it beyond that @Hearth

Comment: why do we ... We don't. Unthink that thought.

Comment: Here's an interesting addition:  https://www.analogictips.com/memristors-fourth-fundamental-circuit-element/

Comment: Possibly interesting to you, OP: [Memristor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristor).

Comment: "*Why are they enough to capture all possible behavior?*" They're not. "*but that is really captured as a whole in each of these three things already.*" No. Not everything is a resistor, inductor, capacitor or combination thereof.

Comment: why not ? @Neil_UK and DKNguyen

Comment: Simply because they're not. The same as asking "why isn't all mathematics encompassed by addition and subtraction?"

Comment: In the case you mentioned, addition and subtraction are a way to combine more fundamental things which are numbers. The numbers themself encompass the field they set out to encompass (as in all other constructions we do on numbers are based on numbers). However, in this case,  the mentioned three are the basic building blocks for most circuits I've seen , (of course there are batteries and current sources but they don't really give a rule on relating the current and voltage unless paired with mentioned objects)

Comment: @Buraian without going all math on you, the numbers and the opeartions on them you know are far from all that math is about, and they're not sufficient to describe a lot of the math underlying everyday things like Wifi.

Comment: @Buraian I've done this sort of thing a lot, it's a very common pattern. I start to learn something new, at the 'explain this like I'm five' level, and it's really simple. There's a few fundamental building blocks that explain everything I've been told (so far). I then fixate on these few simple things. Then I get upset at the complications that the subject really has.

Comment: @Buraian But with addition and subtraction alone, there are whole classes of numbers you can't reach unless you have numbers in that class already, like the imaginary numbers, or even more simply the non-integer real numbers. If you take them as a given, then yes, you can get from one to another, but you can't go from 1 to i without either having the square root operator or i to begin with.

Comment: I mean, @Buraian, your most famous post is about how to approximate $\pi$ with a Taylor series. You know that a Taylor series can approximate any smooth function, but a) not all functions are smooth and b) only when your Taylor series is infinitely long that approximation becomes an equality. You can't approximate e.g. a diode with resistors, capacitors and inductors, at least not with finitely many. And even with infinitely many, you couldn't describe the time-variant behaviour that a diode has (it's not the same if you apply two pulses shortly after each other or with a lot of pause between)

Comment: So, you're really working from a wrong assumption here. I'm sorry, we can't fix this for you.

Comment: Well of course, it depends on the set of things you are taking as the 'basis' to create everything else @Hearth

Answer (score 9):

It seems like you're wondering why there are only three fundamental linear passive elements, so I'll explain that:

You have two physical quantities at play at the circuit level: voltage and current.

Resistance defines a linear relationship between voltage and current.

Inductance defines a linear relationship between voltage and the rate of change of current.

Capacitance defines a linear relationship between current and the rate of change of voltage.

A linear relationship between the rate of change of voltage and the rate of change of current would be equivalent to one between voltage and current, so resistance covers that too.

Now, you may wonder if there's any linear relationship between current and rate of change of current, or between voltage and rate of change of voltage. As it turns out, you can construct these by combining resistors with capacitors or inductors: a resistor in parallel with an inductor gives you an I-I' relationship, and a resistor in series with a capacitor gives you a V-V' relationship.

So we've covered every possible linear relationship up to first order with just the three elements. Combinations that include more inductors and capacitors in more complex combinations can give you second order relationships, and from there you can extend to third order and fourth, and onward arbitrarily far. As I only have a finite amount of time to write this answer, I don't plan on going through the infinite combinations one by one.

---

I've skipped over one important point here, though. In reality, we can't achieve any possible relationship with just passive elements, because without active elements, you can't have *negative* resistance, capacitance, or inductance. These would be required to span the full space of linear source-free circuits, yet they don't exist. They can be made by using active components, but if we're restricted to passive components only, you can't have negative impedances.

That's not a limitation of the mathematics, which will quite happily handle negative impedances, but a limitation of physical reality, where they simply can't exist--as passive elements, they would violate conservation of energy.

You will also find that if you try to make, for instance, an ideal voltage integrator using only passive elements, you'll find zeroes and infinities coming out of your equations for what the capacitance and resistance should be. That also, of course, is not physically realizable, and in fact in this case the math starts to break down as well--so you can't get *any* linear relationship without adding active elements too. But you can get a limited subset of them. I don't have any rigorous definition for what exactly that subset is--that may be an interesting derivation to run through, but I suspect far more complex than it seems.

Comment: "linear relationship up to first order " Why did you mention 'first order' here?

Comment: Because I hadn't gone through any second-order relationships, such as V-I''. Just first derivatives.

Comment: Following the comments and discussion , I've posted [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571681/simple-examples-of-second-order-circuits-and-quantities-required-to-describe-the)

Comment: @Buraian You misunderstood my answer--you can get second-, third-, fourth-, fifth-order, as far up as you want, linear circuits with just resistors, capacitors, and inductors. You need active elements if you want anything *nonlinear*, but you can get whatever order you want.

Comment: Wait so... the active elements are causes linearity? And even in those circuits is the same division of quantites?

Comment: There is a theoretical 4th passive, the memristor. Resistance links voltage and current. Capacitance links charge and voltage. Inductance links magnetic flux and current. Memristor links magnetic flux and charge.

Comment: @Buraian "division of quantities"? And no, active elements are not necessary for linearity. Active elements are needed for any nonlinear functions, though.

Comment: My bad I made a typo I meant non linearity yes

Answer (score 0):

In an electric circuit, we are tracking charge. At any point in a circuit we are keeping track of three things: how much charge is present, how much charge is moving across that point, and how much pressure are the moving charges under.

We call charge Q.

We call amount of charge that is moving, current (I).

We call the pressure behind the moving charge voltage (V). If the circuit is closed and charge is allowed to flow then the pressure determines the speed that charge flows. But when the circuit is open the flow stops and reaches a steady pressure (voltage) at each point.

Just picture a circuit as a pipeline for charge.